# Chinese notification flashes very briefly in Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, malware, notifications

I have this odd behavior on several Chrome instances that are synchronized over different computers. For a very brief moment (like the 10th of a second), a notification with Chinese text appears and immediately disappears again.

This happens roughly two times a day so there is no way I could wait for it. The time also does not appear to be relevant as the last one appeared four minutes past four o'clock.

I'm afraid this might be malware. I'm running Linux Mint 17 and 18 and the notifications appear on both types of system. My extensions are all trustworthy (I guess).

I already removed all notification permissions but the problem persists. Is there a way to find out the cause of this notification? Like to log notifications to a file or something like that? Thanks.

Comment: What you describe isn't malware.

Comment: @Ramhound "I'm _afraid_ this might be malware"?

Comment: Good News, it isn't malware

Comment: Mind elucidating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my old and slow desktop PC, the message showed long enough for me to read it. It was a push notification from the Xiaomi Services Framework on my Android phone forwarded by Pushbullet. No malware then. I'm still not sure though why it used to show only for the fraction of a second.

In the unlikely case anyone has the same problem: the solution was to turn off Mi Notifications in the settings of the Messaging app...